# Spring REST controllers in non spring managed application

Tags: spring, rest, servlets

Do you think it would be possible to create spring rest controllers and use them in another non-spring managed web application deployed on Tomcat? I know I'm able to use spring, annotation based components in my app just by creating manually AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, but the question is if there is a chance to integrate Spring REST controllers with servlets available in this non-spring managed Web App.

The web App is based on gosu language and uses gosu servlets. Gosu servlet is:

public class GosuServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

I coud add new servlets by adding new entries to servlet-config.xml file. For example: I could add

```
public class MyServlet extends GosuServlet {
private DispatcherServlet springServlet;

protected void service( req, res ) {
   springServlet.service( req, res );
}
```

And then, delegate calls

Comment: Yes. The spring dispatcher servlet is just another servlet. It can coexist with other servlets if you want to.

Comment: And what about handler mapping? I know the mapping is created automatically during spring boot application initialization. How could I launch it programatically?

Comment: It seems that bean RequestMappingHandlerMapping is responsible for creating the mapping and probably it will be done automatically (a part of afterPropertiesSet) when getting the bean from appContext.

Comment: What do you mean non-spring managed app? A app that do not use spring ioc container / applicationContext ?

Comment: Yes. Normally this app does not use DI. You're responsible for object instantation.